# get_image_tag & wp_get_attachment_image_attributes behaving strangely

Tags: images

I am new to Wordpress development. I had to apply a filter to add a custom HTML attribute to the image fields. I managed to add a custom input field to the media uploader and store the metadata in the database. The problem I am facing is while retrieving the information.

I tried two different filters, `get_image_tag` & `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filters but both work strangely.

1) `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter adds the html attribute, but only to featured images and not regular images. I would love if I could make it work with regular blog post images too.

Why doesn't `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` work for regular blog post images? It is not mentioned anywhere in the docs that the filter is only meant for featured images.

2) `get_image_tag filter` would only work for new images I upload & not the old ones so I don't prefer it but as `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` didn't work properly, I gave it a try. I have the following code:

```
add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'wpse_235266_image_html', 10, 6 );

function wpse_235266_image_html( $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ) {

    $html = str_replace( '<img ', "<img data='b' ", $html );
    return $html;

}
```

Now after hit & trial, I found that the above works only if I replace **data** with **data-X** where *X* is any string.

**Why does the HTML attribute need to have a hyphen?**

Answer (score 0):

Featured images are stored separately in the database and retrieved with a [separate function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/). So it is possible to attach a filter to that function. Regular images are just strings in the post field or in a widget. You can still filter those, but it takes more effort. The filter you built on `get_image_tag` can also be used on [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) (for posts and pages) and [`widget_text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_text/) (for the text widget).

Beware that if you have already used the filter on `get_image_tag`, your data attribute is already included as a string in the post, so if you use the filter again it will be included twice, unless you include a test for its presence.

As for the hyphen in the data attribute, that's simply how the [attribute is defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Just `data` is invalid html.

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't undestand why wp_get_attachment_image_attributes is only working for featured images and not regular post images? I mean the filter name says get attachment image attributes. It doesn't say it is only for featured images

Comment: It should work the moment you insert the image in the post. But once it is a html string in the post the function isn't called anymore. You can work around this by including images with the gallery shortcode.

Comment: "It should work the moment you insert the image in the post", you're talking about the `get_image_tag` while I am asking about `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` in my previous comment. `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes ` is called everytime a featured image is displayed on my blog, it just doesn't get called for regular blog post images.